# Arduino Uno with Kubuntu 16.04: Unable to enumerate device

Tags: arduino-uno, linux, ubuntu

I try to connect my arduino uno R1 in order to program the atmega8u2 but I am not able to do so. When I run `sudo dfu-programmer atmega8u2 erase` I get the following results:

```
dfu-programmer: no device present.
```

So in order to diagnose it i run `dmeesg` with the following results:

```
 [ 1395.921051] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 30 using
 xhci_hcd [ 1396.041175] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [ 1396.269135] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [
 1396.497109] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 31 using xhci_hcd [ 1396.617169] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71
 [ 1396.845177] usb 2-3: device descriptor read/64, error -71 [
 1397.073163] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 32 using xhci_hcd [ 1397.073371] usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup
 address. [ 1397.281311] usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup
 address. [ 1397.489086] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 32,
 error -71 [ 1397.609173] usb 2-3: new full-speed USB device number 33
 using xhci_hcd [ 1397.609382] usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup
 address. [ 1397.817200] usb 2-3: Device not responding to setup
 address. [ 1398.025176] usb 2-3: device not accepting address 33,
 error -71 [ 1398.025235] usb usb2-port3: unable to enumerate USB
 device
```

Do you know fellows how to make my arduino connect back into my computer?

Furthermore II forgot to mention my user is in `dialout` group as `groups` gnu/linux command mentions:

```
pcmagas adm dialout cdrom sudo dip plugdev lpadmin sambashare libvirtd docker wireshark
```

PS: That thing happened after soldering the resistor into the board so it is a new problem.

Comment: Looks like your board is either electrically damaged, or by previous attempts you put it in a bad software state where it does not function as a USB device.  If it is recoverable over USB, it would be by doing something electrically on startup to force it into a factory firmware recovery mode.  Likely you need to read the instructions you are following more thoroughly.  **Did you solder the resistor as instructed** at https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2 ??

Comment: Well the board has already this problem: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/how-to-re-solder-the-resistor-in-order-to-reprogram-the-atmega8u2 I somehow managed to solder back the resistor in order to reprogram it in order to fix this problem but the problem still remains. The poer led works as ussual and the led in pin 13 blinks when I press the reset button.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to re-solder the resistor in order to reprogram the Atmega8U2](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/50807/how-to-re-solder-the-resistor-in-order-to-reprogram-the-atmega8u2)

Comment: And how do you know you were successful in soldering the resistor?  You have not achieved what the resistor should, so either it is not connected, or you're not doing the reset required after plugging in the USB, or there's another electrical fault on your board that disables the 8u2 but not the 328p.  This looks like a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should solder the resistor (in case you do not have the skills I reccomend doing into a proffessional, a professional close to me managed to solder it with a cost about 5 euros) and then hardware reset the atmega8u2 the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2) mentions. For quick reference just look over in this image:

[image: Where to reset atmega8u2]

In the `dmesg` you will see similar the same or message:

```
[ 1544.679504] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 1544.808341] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=2ff7
[ 1544.808350] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1544.808356] usb 1-6: Product: Arduino Uno DFU
```

Then look on the similar [question](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/52032/arduino-uno-r1-i-soldered-resistor-but-i-cannot-dfu-program-atmega8u2) for R1 boards or in case you have a newer board then follow the instructions mentiones to the [documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2).