# Arduino Uno R1 I soldered resistor but I cannot DFU program atmega8u2

Tags: arduino-uno, usb, programmer

I have an Arduino R1 board (the very first one) and I managed to solder the resistor into Arduino's Atmega8u2 (I went to a specialist in order to do that). Then I reset atmega8u2 and by wiring the pins mentioned in: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Hacking/DFUProgramming8U2

I can confirm it via this message over my GNU/Linux machine by running `dmesg`:

```
[ 1544.679504] usb 1-6: new full-speed USB device number 42 using xhci_hcd
[ 1544.808341] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=03eb, idProduct=2ff7
[ 1544.808350] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[ 1544.808356] usb 1-6: Product: Arduino Uno DFU
```

I also to confirm that I run `lsusb` and I got the following result:

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 248a:8367  
Bus 001 Device 058: ID 03eb:2ff7 Atmel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Further indicating to me that arduino is in DFU mode over my ubuntu 16.04 machine. Also I further verify via `dfu-util -l` command:

```
Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2014 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to dfu-util@lists.gnumonks.org

Found DFU: [03eb:2ff7] ver=0000, devnum=63, cfg=1, intf=0, alt=0, name="UNKNOWN", serial="UNKNOWN"
```

The I try to run:

`sudo dfu-programmer atmega8u2 erase`

But for some reason I get the following error:
`dfu-programmer: no device present.`

Do you know why I get this error and how I can fix it?

## Edit 1

I installed the latest version of dfu-programmer and compiled from source via https://sourceforge.net/projects/dfu-programmer/files/dfu-programmer/0.7.2/ but still I get the error. I also tried to compile it with `libusb-1.0.0`

## Edit2

I also tried [this](https://github.com/swinman/dfu-programmer/tree/libusb_no_device) version with `libusb-1.0.0` but still the same error occurs.

## Edit 3

As many suggest I tried to do multiple times but still I get this error.

## Edit 4

I also used `dfu-util` and I try to insert the data into the atmega8u2 via:

```
 sudo dfu-util -d 03eb:2ff7 -D ./Arduino-usbserial-uno.hex -R
```

But I get the error:

```
dfu-util 0.8

Copyright 2005-2009 Weston Schmidt, Harald Welte and OpenMoko Inc.
Copyright 2010-2014 Tormod Volden and Stefan Schmidt
This program is Free Software and has ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
Please report bugs to dfu-util@lists.gnumonks.org

dfu-util: Invalid DFU suffix signature
dfu-util: A valid DFU suffix will be required in a future dfu-util release!!!
Opening DFU capable USB device...
ID 03eb:2ff7
Run-time device DFU version 0100
Claiming USB DFU Interface...
Setting Alternate Setting #0 ...
Determining device status: state = dfuIDLE, status = 0
dfuIDLE, continuing
DFU mode device DFU version 0100
Device returned transfer size 3072
Copying data from PC to DFU device
Download    [                         ]   0%            0 bytesdfu-util: Error during download
dfu-util: can't detach
Resetting USB to switch back to runtime mode
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://gebloggendings.wordpress.com/category/elektronik/arduino/ it is sometimes not to assume that the `atmega8u2` is always the correct value in my case was the `at90usb82` resulting into using the following command sequence:

```
sudo dfu-programmer at90usb82 erase
# Flashing the arduino provided .hex
sudo dfu-programmer at90usb82 /usr/share/arduino/hardware/arduino/firmwares/atmegaxxu2/arduino-usbserial/Arduino-usbserial-uno.hex
# reset the board 
sudo dfu-programmer at90usb82 reset
```

Further information you can find into:

- https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=53443.0
- https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=542854.0